# Конструкторы классов

Tags: c++

Дословно вопрос звучит так "Define the constructor for class Z". Помогите разобраться что именно надо реализовать? Ну тип конструктор у класса Z уже есть, чего не хватает? Мне важно понять что требуется и как это реализовывать чтобы в дальнейшем я сам мог решать такие задачи.

```
class A
{
public:
    A ( int a ) { aa_ = a; }
private:
    int aa_;
};

class Z
{
public:
    Z();
private:
    const int & r_;
    const int i_;
    A a_;
};
```

Comment: Я так понимаю задание состоит в том чтобы написать именно определение конструктора, то есть напишите код для него. Чтобы он инициализировал переменные к примеру

Comment: "Define" означает "определить". *Определения* конструктора для `Z` у вас пока нет. Пока что у вас есть только *объявление*.

Answer (score 0):

При создании любого конструктора в классе другие конструкторы по умолчанию не создаются допустим если в классе А создан конструктор А (int a) то конструктор по умолчанию и конструктор копирования уже не создаются автоматически

```
class A
{
public:
    A ( int a ) { aa_ = a; }
private:
    int aa_;
};

class Z
{
public:
    Z(int a, int r, int i) :  r_(r), i_(i), a_(a) {}
private:
    const int & r_;
    const int i_;
    A a_;
};
```

Comment: Про конструктор копирования - неверно. Конструктор копирования объявляется *всегда*. Подавить неявное объявление конструктора копирования можно только явно объявив свой конструктор копирования. Также в данном классе будет неявно объявлен конструктор перемещения. Что произойдет с *определениями* этих конструкторов - отдельная история, но объявлены они будут.